# Bluetooth getting turned off on Nexus 6P and Nexus 6 with Android 6

Tags: altbeacon

We have noticed weird issue on Nexus 6P and Nexus 6 device with Android 6(Marshmallow). After installing our Android app on device which is using Altbeacon library 2+, causes the bluetooth turned off in couple of days and there is no way to turned on back. Only way to turned on is to do factory reset the device.

Has anyone seen this issue on Android 6?

-Parveen

Comment: Same application works fine on Samsung S5 and S3 device without any problems using Android 5.

Comment: Have you tried with [Locate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en) application? This app also uses Altbeacon Library. It would be helpful to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I haven't tried Locate application running on Android 6. Will install it on same device and will update with results.

Comment: Issue happened again after 7 days of using the app which uses altbeacon library. Now will try with Locate application.

Comment: I found that altbeacon 2.8.1 is not working on my nexus 6 running 6.0.1.